# DATE not inserted using JPA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a sample mysql database as such :

```
ID(int) :
Name(varchar) :
Address(varchar):
dob(DATE):
```

Using the netbeans webservices, I have the variable dob using java.util.date.

While from the Generated JPA Entity Classes, i have :

```
@Column(name = "dob")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dob;
```

During persist, all fields get inserted into the database except DOB.
I have tried giving all possible default, `12/12/2013, 2013/12/12` etc but i get a null in that column in the database while the other column values are present. I don't get any errors in the glassfish console.

Comment: Have you tried: @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)? In Postgre we must always use TemporalType.TIMESTAMP, because the TemporalType.DATE not always works...

Comment: If you are using spring mvc you must register a date binder. http://ankeetmaini.wordpress.com/2012/01/24/binding-date-in-spring/

Comment: @sergiu i am not using spring, just the normal JPA entities i think that is generated from netbeans.

Comment: Can you provide more information such as how you are setting the dob value and the JPA providers being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that, I was not receiving Date as Date from user input(textbox).Although it was date, it's obvious that the client will be putting String instead. Once i did the parsing and formatting, all went well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.sql.Timestamp` instead of `Date`.

```
@Column(name = "dob")
private java.sql.Timestamp dob;
```